# does the function in a python program written using sched, impact/block the the other functionality in the program?

Tags: python, module, scheduler

I am new to the programming world and trying out something with Python.
My requirement is to have http web server(built using BaseHTTPServer) that runs forever, which takes an input binary file through HTML form based on user selection and returns a set of HTML files back on the web client.
As part of this when the user is selecting his specific input file, there are set of folders created with HTML files written inside those folders in the server, i thought of putting in a tidy up functionality for these folders on the server. So that everyday the tidy up would clean up the folders automatically based on a configuration.

i could build both these modules in my script(http web service & tidy up on server), specifically the tidy up part is achieved using python's sched module

Both of these functionalities are working independently, i.e

- when i comment out the function for tidy up, i can access the server url in the browser and the index.html page shows up correctly and further(accepts binary, parsing happens and output htmls are returned)
- when i comment out the function for http server, based on the configuration set, i am able to ensure the tidy up functionality is working
- But when i have both these functions in place, i see that the tidy up function works/is invoked correctly for the scheduled time, but the index.html page is not loaded when i request for the server on the browser

I researched on the sched module enough to understand that it is just to schedule multiple events on the system by setting time delays and priorities
Not able to work both the functionality

Questions:

1. Is this a correct approach, using sched to achieve the tidy up?
2. If yes, what could be the reason that the http service functionality is blocked and only the tidy up is working?

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, changed the function call for the tidy up feature, by using the background scheduler implementation of the APScheduler module of python.
This does not impact the function for serving http requests and has currently solved my problem